# In struts tag have to test whether the string1 contains string2

Tags: string, struts2, contains

Hi i want to check the string in struts tag..
How to check whether the `string1` conatins the `string2` value?

for eg:

```
string1 = strutstag 
string2 = tag
```

i want to do some logic if `string1` contains `string2` value

help me to do this... thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:-

```
<s:if test="string1.indexOf(string2) != -1">
True
</s:if>
```

### EDIT

As per your update, variable representation in `IF` condition is wrong.
It should be represented with `#` symbol

```
<s:set name="string" value="%{'test'}" />
<s:set name="string1" value="%{'result'}" />
<s:if test="%{#counter.indexOf(#counter1) == -1}">
    <font size="5" color="green">String Not Found.</font>
</s:if>
<s:else>
    <font size="5" color="green">String Found.</font>
</s:else>
```

In your code, there is no `counter` related variable.

Your condition should be

```
<s:if test="%{#string.indexOf(#string1) == -1}">
```

Comment: <s:set name="string" value ="test" />
                <s:set name="string1" value ="result" />
                <s:if test="%{counter.indexOf(counter1) == -1}"> <font size="5" color="green">String Not Found.</font></s:if>
                <s:else><font size="5" color="green">String Found.</font></s:else> I have tried as like this but it always print the else part.. is any mistake i did in this

Comment: @Shakthi: for a variable, you should represent with `#` symbol (`#counter` and `#counter1`).